# add borders around multiple cells on excel c#

Tags: c#, excel, windows-forms-designer

I am currently using Microsoft.Office.Core; and using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; to export my data from windows form to excel to export data from windows form c# to excel

Is there any chance to add a border on selected cells like 
[How i need it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmJrj.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, heres a function I made for the same thing

```
/// <summary>
/// Puts a border around range
/// </summary>
/// <param name="ws">Excel worksheet</param>
/// <param name="r1">First Row</param>
/// <param name="c1">First Column</param>
/// <param name="r2">Last Row</param>
/// <param name="c2">Last Column</param>
/// <param name="weight">Border Brush Weight</param>
public void BorderRange(Worksheet ws, int r1, int c1, int r2, int c2, XlBorderWeight weight = XlBorderWeight.xlThin)
{
    Range r = ws.Range[ws.Cells[r1, c1], ws.Cells[r2, c2]];
    r.BorderAround2(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous, weight);
}
```

You'll need to call it a few times to put the borders round the ranges you need.

Comment: I noticed the previous code put borders around every cell in the range, but I guess you want to put the border only around the range itself. I've updated the code. Does that help? If not --- what isn't working exactly?

Comment: @vulcan -- I'd encourage you to try it again or post your code where this is not working.  The solution, as posted, works exactly as you requested

Comment: @HamboneI am trying to find the code for the border. Because I tried to  find online and try to modify to  what I need it cant be done